# MySQL Datatype for storing integers starting from Zero?

Tags: mysql, types

I have to store `isdCodes` which is in format `0091` `001` `009751` `009665` etc. in the database, the initial will basically start from zero. i tried using int as datatype with unsigned attribute but it does not seems to work. which datatype is suitable for storing this type of value?

Comment: You can use int but output it formating 00{int}...

Comment: @Good.Dima Does not work since IDD prefix is in most cases `00` but not always. It starts in most cases with `0` but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Does not work since IDD prefix is in most cases `00` but not always. It starts in most cases with `0` but not always.***

Since the number of leading zeros matter, (i.e., `0091` ≠ `091`), I would go for a `varchar` in this case.

If you really want to use some numeric type, I guess you could prepend a `1` in front of the number to keep the zeros, but it would be a bit of a hack.

Comment: nope i won't be, but is it ok since i will be storing just the integers?

Comment: Using varchar for numbers? I don't see a major problem with it unless you're storing gigabytes of these numbers. If the number of leading zeros actually matter, I don't think a numeric type is appropriate.

Comment: There's no need to use varchar and concatenation... If you use a zerofilled value, the db cares about the leading zeros only when outputting information. A `SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = 1` will select the row which has a value of 1, no matter how much leading zeros it has.

Comment: Even the hack with `1` would not work for every ISD code including the IDD prefix since IDD prefixes like `8~10`exist which are dialed with your phone as `8**10`. So for me there is no question about what datatype to use: It must be something like `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some varchar for that since **ISD codes are** not something you want to "calculate with" and are a **sequence of digits rather than a whole number itself**. The leading `0` and `00` thing shows that very good.

**Edit**
Just saw that IDD prefixes like `8~10` exist. So there is no way to use a number-like datatype. You have to use something like varchar or similar if you want be able to store any ISD code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ZEROFILL, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE test (value int zerofill);

INSERT INTO test values(1), (20), (515);
```

Comment: the problem using zero fill is it will fill with all the zeros, for example if i have decalred int(11) then it will fill the values with `00000000001` instead of just `001`

Comment: You can change the precision of the field, but I don't know if this will help. What are the values that you will store? Different numbers, all starting with '00'? This doesn't make much sense to me, but since you're unhappy with what the precision gives you, I'm not sure what you want to accomplish...

Comment: @Ibrahim, updated my answer for selecting `1` -> `001` and `1000` -> `001000`.