# First 0 disappearing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How do I tell phpmyadmin, MySQL to allow the first 0 in front of a phone number for example ? (Not a zero fill)

- When I try to put a zero in front of it (in phpmyadmin), it removes it automatically.
- When I submit my form number with the 0 specified in front of the number it doesn't add it.

Is there a workaround or something ?

Comment: What's the column type in the table?

Comment: Perhaps you are using an integer type and not a string, or the formatting is off.

Comment: The column type is integer

Comment: And even for integer type is there a workaround ?

Comment: sprint() when you echo the value

Comment: Use `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` and not `INT`. The integer datatype will trim leading zeros and is not appropriate for phone numbers.

Comment: indeed sprint() might work, but what if column type allow's null and sprint is set in a foreach loop ?

Comment: Ok thanks Bad wolf, i'll change it right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786193/allow-number-to-start-with-zero-when-stored-in-mysql-integer-field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279723/mysql-datatype-for-storing-integers-starting-from-zero

Comment: How are you storing phone numbers in a numerical field? Don't. Some phone numbers are 12-18 digits long and include important extension information.

Comment: @Rohit, indeed it was already posted, don't saw it with the keywords I searched.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `INT` datatype in mysql stores just that, an integer. As you would expect with the integer datatype in any programming language, the database engine trims off any leading zeros and rounds any decimal points, making it inappropriate for storing phone numbers.

If the number of digits in the phone number is always the same, use the datatype `CHAR(length)` instead, or if it's not use the datatype `VARCHAR(max_length)`. These will store the exact value entered rather than an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

When using mysql, and php dont put your string in this way:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bids SET time_off = ".$editend." WHERE id = '" . $editbid_id . "'");
```

without a single quote around your var (which is a string number). do this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bids SET time_off = '".$editend."' WHERE id = '" . $editbid_id . "'");
```

in other words, make sure there are quotes around the var you put it into the db, otherwise it will see it as a numeric value and remove your leading 0, even if your field is a string value.

Answer (score 1):

When storing numbers that might have a 0 in front, use a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` data type.  Phone numbers, zip codes, product SKUs are prime examples of where you should always use a non number variable type.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can leave the PHONE in the 'int' format, and add the leading zeroes when you select it.

Like this:

```
select right('0000000000'+convert(varchar(10), PHONE), 10)
```

-- if your phone numbers have more than 10 digits, you adjust accordingly