# MySQL WHERE clause integer comparison with alphabet characters still positive?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I'm searching a specific row by:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '0003'
```

Wherein column `id` is an INT primary key field, and it returns me the row of `id` = 3

Again if I search by:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '3df'
```

It still returns me the row of `id` = 3

This is really weird. Why?

My Mysql version is 5.7.14 community.

Comment: I hope this answer will be helpful for your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278332/first-0-disappearing?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL does implicit conversion of strings to numbers, in a numeric context.

It does so by converting the leading digits, and stopping at the first non-digit.  Most databases would return a type conversion error.

The moral?  Always ensure that the types are compatible before doing such a comparison.  If you like, you can change this to an explicit case:

```
where id = cast('3df' as unsigned)
```

In this case, you will get the type conversion error.